# Products Details Scrapping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrap product image, Product name and product price from this URL https://glomark.lk/fresh/vegetable/low-country-vegetable/sc/799

Here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

link = "https://glomark.lk/fresh/vegetable/low-country-vegetable/sc/799"
page = requests.get(link)
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
products = []
prices = []
images = []
for data in soup.findAll('div',class_='item'):
    product_name_element = data.find('h3', class_='product-title')
    product_name = product_name_element.find('span', class_='light-font').text.strip()
    image=data.find('img')
    products.append(product_name)
    images.append(image.get('src'))
```

It is giving Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_24796\1606044086.py in <module>
     10 for data in soup.findAll('div',class_='item'):
     11         product_name_element = data.find('h3', class_='product-title')
---> 12         product_name = product_name_element.find('span', class_='light-font').text.strip()
     13         image=data.find('img')
     14         products.append(product_name)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Answer (score 0):

That means there's some `div.item` that doesn't have a title.

You'll probably want to skip those - maybe print the item so you can figure out what happened:

```
for data in soup.findAll('div',class_='item'):
    product_name_element = data.find('h3', class_='product-title')
    if product_name_element is None:
        print("Oops!", data)
        continue
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to locate items only in search results `<div>`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

link = "https://glomark.lk/fresh/vegetable/low-country-vegetable/sc/799"
page = requests.get(link)
soup = bs(page.content, "html.parser")

products = []
prices = []
images = []
for data in soup.select(".search-results .item"):  # <-- locate items only in search results
    product_name_element = data.find("h3", class_="product-title")
    product_name = product_name_element.find("span", class_="light-font").text.strip()
    image = data.find("img")
    products.append(product_name)
    images.append(image.get("src"))

print(images)
```

Prints:

```
[
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310310--01--1555692325.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310074--01--1555692319.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310101--1--1559720635.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310128--01--1555692321.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310066--01--1555692319.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310044--1--1559720634.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310084--01--1555692319.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310098--1--1559720634.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310102--1--1557729009.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310092--01--1555692319.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310135--1--1559720635.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310096--1--1559720634.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310062--01--1555692319.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310099--1--1559720635.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310136--1--1559720635.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310077--01--1555692319.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310064--1--1559720634.jpeg",
    "https://objectstorage.ap-mumbai-1.oraclecloud.com/n/softlogicbicloud/b/cdn/o/products/140-140/310127--01--1555692320.jpeg",
]
```